# Multi Column Attribute Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a composite virtual attribute in a Rails 3.0.3 model how can errors on component attributes be automatically placed on the composite attribute? For example:

```
validates_presence_of :first_name
validates_presence_of :last_name

def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end

def name=(name)
   first_name, last_name = name.split
end
```

Gives:

`@model.errors[:name] = @model.errors[:first_name] + @model.errors[:last_name]`

Please note that this is a simplified example and I can't easily move the validations from the component attributes into a new validation method for the composite attribute.

Another example is the Paperclip gem in which validations on the size (attachment_size) are placed on the attribute 'attachment'. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with:

```
after_validation do

  self.errors[:first_name].each do |message|
    self.errors.add(:name, message)
  end

  self.errors[:last_name].each do |message|
    self.errors.add(:name, message)
  end

  self.errors.delete(:first_name)
  self.errors.delete(:last_name)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not have any "normal" validations on the `first_name` and `last_name` fields. Instead, I would leave it in the capable hands of a custom validator:

```
validate :name_is_valid

def name_is_valid
  if first_name.blank? || last_name.blank?
    errors.add(:name, "You must specify both your first and last name")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Ryan. Sorry, to clarify my example is much more complex than the above. I'm actually looking for something closer to how `Paperclip` validates the attachment size, attachment type, etc and adds all the validations to the base attribute (but I couldn't figure it out from reading the source). I'll update the above to be more clear.